# WinPE - Populate a HTA textarea from saved text file

Tags: javascript, html

I have a batch file than runs under WinPE, the program creates and updates a text file as it runs. I want to create a simple 'front end' using HTA that displays a logo and the text file as it updates. 
I have got the logo displayed and have a textarea to display the contents of the text file .. however it doesn't update as the text file changes.

Here is my HTA code so far;

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Live Text Display</title>

        <HTA:APPLICATION 
            ID=“Display”
            APPLICATIONNAME="Display"
            SCROLL="no"
            SINGLEINSTANCE="yes"
            MAXIMIZEBUTTON="no"
            MINIMIZEBUTTON="no"
            WINDOWSTATE="MAXIMIZE"
        >

<style>
        img {
                        width: 45%;
                        height: 25%;
                    }
        textarea {
                        width: 100%;
                        height: 75%;
                        margin: 0 auto;
                        padding: 0;
                        border-width: 0;
                        text-align: center;
                        font-size: 18px;
                        overflow: hidden;
                        resize: none;
                        background-color: yellow;
                        border: none;
                    }
</style>

</head>
<script language="VBScript">

                Option Explicit
                Dim oFSO, oFile, pFSO, pFile, pText, TEXT

                sub Window_onload
                    on error resume next
                    RefreshList
                    iTimerID = window.setInterval("RefreshList", 1000)
                end sub

                SUB RefreshList
                    SET oFSO=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
                    SET oFILE=oFSO.OpenTextFile("HTA.TXT",1)
                    TEXT=oFILE.ReadLine
                    TEXT=Trim(TEXT)
                    document.all.logo.src=TEXT & "\LOGO.JPG"
                    oFILE.Close
                    SET pFSO=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
                    SET pFile=pFSO.OpenTextFile(TEXT & "\PROGRESS.TXT",1)
                    pText=pFile.ReadAll     
                    document.all.ScriptArea.InnerText=pText
                    pFile.Close
                END SUB

</script>

<body>
    <p style="text-align:center">
        <br><img id="logo" width="900" height="150"><br><br>
        <textarea name="ScriptArea" rows="12"></textarea>
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

HTA.TXT contains the drive letter (eg. D:) of a USB that is 'discovered' using commands in the batch program and saved to to the default 'x:\windows\system32' location standard when running in WinPE.

LOGO.JPG is the picture I display on the HTA form.

PROGRESS.TXT is the text file I want the contents of to be displayed in the textarea (named 'ScripArea'). I have tried both;

```
document.all.ScriptArea.InnerText=pText
```

and

```
document.all.ScriptArea.Value=pText
```

to get the update to display .. neither work.

I have included a refresh timer to run the RefreshList subroutine every 1 second.

Any help would be appreciated as I am going crazy trying to figure it out.

Regards.

---

Update:

I now have the issue that when the HTA is called from the batch program the batch program suspends until I physically close the HTA, this results in the PROGRESS file not being updated.

Anyone know why the batch file commands suspend while the HTA is open?

Comment: Element selectors, properties, and methods are case sensitive.  Use `.value`, all lower case, to modify the value of a textarea.  There are other DOM selectors you can use as well.  `document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0].value = pText`, or you could give the textarea an id and then `document.getElementById('scriptArea').value = pText`.

Comment: Thank you for your response, however even trying the case change and the two other options you supplied the textarea is still not updating, it's almost as if the setinterval is not working.

Comment: ok, cheers, thank you for the help .. looks like a little more research for me

Comment: Huh.  It seems I was mistaken [according to this TechNet article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692610.aspx).  Sorry about that.  if I get some time I'll dig into your issue a little more deeply.

Comment: I figured a way round it. It depends on how I run the HTA from the batch file. 

If I run it as 'mshta.exe  Image.hta' then all further commands in the batch file are suspended until Image.hta is complete, however if I run it as 'Start mshta.exe  Image.hta' then the commands in the batch file comtinue to be run alongside the HTA.